# Find the positive minimum of $P=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+y}-\frac{1}{x+y+z}$.

Tags: inequality, integers

Let $x$, $y$, $z$ be positive integers. Find the positive minimum of $$P=\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{x+y}-\dfrac{1}{x+y+z}.$$

The problem is requested to use an one variable continuous function to find the minimum but I have no idea for it, the expression is not symmetric.

Thank you for answer or give me some hints.

Comment: See why $x \ge 3$ and start from there.

Comment: Thank you for answer, i can solve it with your hint, i followed the hint in the book, but it seem to be hard to find the continuous function, this way easier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, it's easy to get $x=3$ because $\dfrac{1}{x} $ is the greatest term following to $\dfrac{1} {2} $ and $x=3$ makes $P$ smaller than any other value of $x$. 
Second, the outcome of the first two terms is $\dfrac{1} {6} $. if $x+y=7$, P is the smallest for the first three term. So $y=4$.
The last term is easy to get $x+y+z=43$. So $z=36$

Comment: Thank you for answer, this way easier than the hint in the book, i followed it but can't find the continuous function.

Comment: -1 Not quite. How do you know that we can't use $ x = 4$ to get a smaller minimum? EG If we wanted to find the positive minimum of $ 0.451 - 1/x - 1/(x+y)$, then observe that $ 0.451 - 1/4 - 1/5 < 0.451 - 1/3 - 1/9$.